# Round the result to 2 decimal place using html and javascript

Tags: html, math

```
   <script>
     function e(element)
     {
        return document.getElementById(element);
     }

     function f(element)
     {
        return parseFloat(e(element).value);
     }

     function updateResult()
     {

        e("inputK").value = f("inputG")*1.33* (f("inputI")/(f("inputH")+ f("inputI")))
     }

  </script>
```

I request help in rounding the values to 2 decimal place for the code displayed above

> result-- input type="text" id="inputK" readonly="true"
>   i have tried math.round(inputK) it does not work
>   your suggestion will help me in improving the result.

Comment: There is no Java here.

Comment: possibly duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour] and read the [help]. At StackOverflow, it is preferred that you put effort into solving your question first. There are many answers to this exact question on the internet including this website.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you are using [Math.round()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-math-round-function/) which returns integer only. There are multiple ways to achieve the goal.

1. `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` -- returns number
2. `var numb = 123.23454;
    numb = numb.toFixed(2);`  -- returns string
3. `Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2"` -- returns number
4. `Number.prototype.round = function(places) {
     return +(Math.round(this + "e+" + places)  + "e-" + places);
    }` -- returns number

Answer (score 0):

```
e("inputK").value= f("inputK").toFixed(2);
```

the following code helps in getting me the solution for two decimal place
thank you